# How to use dao factory pattern for login and registration dao

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I am using separate DAO classes for login and registration as follows:

Registration DAO:

```
public class RegistrationDAO {

    public void insert(UserProfile user) {
        try {
            Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "insert into TBL_USER (USR_FIRST_NAME,USR_LST_NAME,USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL,USR_PASSWORD) values(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

            pst.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            pst.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            pst.setString(3, user.getEmail());
            pst.setString(4, user.getPassword());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("@@@@Record insertion error in Registration DAO@@@@");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Login DAO:

```
public class LoginDAO {

    public boolean authenticate(String email, String password)
            throws Exception {
        boolean isUser = false;
        try {
            Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL, USR_PASSWORD from TBL_USER where USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL=? and USR_PASSWORD=?");
            statement.setString(1, email);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                isUser = true;
                System.out.println("User authenticated successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid username or password!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("DB related Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isUser;
    }
}
```

Lets say if I change my database from oracle to mySql in future then I should be able to connect. I came to know that DAO factory and DAO interface must be used to connect to multiple databases, but I am not able to figure how to apply it in my case.

Do I need to have two DAO interfaces for RegistatrationDao and LoginDao respectively? what is better way of achieving this?

Comment: Don't over-engineer. The chance of changing the database is close to null. And if you do, you won't be willing to maintain the code for both databases just in case you switch back to Oracle. I'd concentrate on correctly closing the connections and statements, and on dealing with transactions correctly and declaratively if I were you.

Comment: @JBNizet So there is no need having a DAO interface or factory in my case? Just keep it as is apart from closing the connections etc?

Comment: An interface and a factory might still be useful, but not for the reasons you state. But I would use dependency injection (Spring, CDI) instead of using a factory to get the DAOs. That's what will really make your code simpler and, more importantly, much more testable. And that's what will also help having declarative transaction handling.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public interface LoginDAO {
                    public boolean authenticate(String email, String password) throws Exception;
                }

    public class OracleLoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {
               public boolean authenticate(String email, String password) throws Exception {
                  //Oracle specific implementation goes here.
               }
        }

    public class MySqlLoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {
               public boolean authenticate(String email, String password) throws Exception {
                  //MySQL specific implementation goes here.
               }
        }

//NOW IN YOUR LOGIN Service
public class LoginService {
   private LoginDAO loginDAO = new OracleLoginDAOImpl ();
   //OR U CAN USE MYSQLDAO As BELOW
   //private LoginDAO loginDAO = new MySqlLoginDAOImpl();
    loginDAO.autheticate("user","password");
}
```

//Similarly create Interface for RegistrationDAO and its Oracle and MySQL implementation classes.

Comment: Thank you. That helped in understanding dao pattern implementation. This looks simple and correct then what is need of going for factories ? I have seen so many people choosing factories along with dao interface?

Comment: this link will be helpful for you 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html